Sliding Sync for ElementX
I'm trying to follow up  the steps in GitHub repository about setting up sliding sync but i have problems in configuration.
Let's say for example that the IP address of the  server is 192.168.x.y and I access it through my machine that has this IP address 192.168.a.b via http://192.168.x.y:8008
Here is the content of docker-compose.yml file:
version: '2.3'
services:
  postgres:
    image: postgres:14
    restart: unless-stopped
    volumes:
     - ./postgresdata:/var/lib/postgresql/data

    # These will be used in homeserver.yaml later on
    environment:
     - POSTGRES_DB=synapse
     - POSTGRES_USER=USER
     - POSTGRES_PASSWORD=PASSWORD
     
  element:
    image: vectorim/element-web:latest
    restart: unless-stopped
    volumes:
      - ./element-config.json:/app/config.json
        
  synapse:
    image: matrixdotorg/synapse:latest
    restart: unless-stopped
    volumes:
     - ./synapse:/data


Here is the content of homeserver.yml file
server_name: "matrix.example.com"
pid_file: /data/homeserver.pid
listeners:
  - port: 8008
    tls: false
    type: http
    x_forwarded: true
    resources:
      - names: [client, federation]
        compress: false
          #database:
  #name: sqlite3
    #args:
    #database: /data/homeserver.db
database:
  name: psycopg2
  args:
    user: USER
    password: PASSWORD
    database: synapse
    host: postgres
    cp_min: 5
    cp_max: 10
log_config: "/data/matrix.example.com.log.config"
media_store_path: /data/media_store
registration_shared_secret: "Q4gpze#T-ZIqsvK0-JeW,nu,qIreJERwpEP4qEo~Q.1iFzFb4="
report_stats: true
macaroon_secret_key: "8T-Tk0Lv6GE30+7dyxs:vBP4e~CZx9+=ZR3.Vq#sh8pJREvL_X"
form_secret: "NRt44hz9RvUar#~BHMdWBkDgXJLBkdI+=Pe-&_aqedv=KDE,Gs"
signing_key_path: "/data/matrix.example.com.signing.key"
trusted_key_servers:
  - server_name: "matrix.org"

now that i try to run the proxy

SYNCV3_SECRET=$(cat /home/application/.secret) SYNCV3_SERVER="http://192.168.x.y:8008" SYNCV3_DB="user=USER dbname=syncv3 sslmode=disable password='PASSWORD'" SYNCV3_BINDADDR=0.0.0.0:8008 ./syncv3

I receive this error

panic: pq: password authentication failed for user "USER"


hi, i'm still stuck in this configuration, is there anyone who can help me please?
